# xmlstarlet: How to insert nested element?

Tags: xml, batch-file

Im trying to add one `<Product>` element with  nested -> to the `<Products>` list.

From this XML:

```
<Products>
  <Product>
    <Name>
      product1
    </Name>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

Want to finish like this:

```
<Products>
  <Product>
    <Name>
      product1
    </Name>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Name>
      product2
    </Name>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

this is my snippet attemp:

```
xmlstarlet ed --inplace -s /Products -t elem -n "Product" -v "" \
-s //Product -t elem -n "name" -v "product2" \
Settings.xml
```

the problem is that every current `<Product>` is get 1 more `<Name>` element:

```
  <Products>
    <Product>
      <name>
        product1
      </name>
      <name>
        product2
      </name>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <name>
        product2
      </name>
    </Product>
  <Products>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way

```
xmlstarlet ed --subnode "//Products" --type elem -n Product \
--subnode "//Products/Product[last()]" --type elem -n \n
"Name"  --value "product2" Settings.xml
```

and see if it works.